# SQL Agent / Task Scheduler Alternative

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks, console-application, sql-agent

I have a machine running Windows 10.

I have a console app that produces a .exe that needs to constantly run on that machine.

Currently I am using Windows task scheduler to run the .exe however find it very clunky and unreliable.

I am not in a position to purchase SQL standard to get a SQL agent license.

So I am looking for a cost effective robust program or service that will run my exe on a schedule. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert this to to a windows service and implement config for intervals of when it should run? A simple service  that takes the interval times from the config file and convert the current .exe into a .dll, then running the .dll in a while loop, when it has finished wait the specified interval time. A quick example might look like:

```
OnStart()
{
    //do stuff and get config and specify thread with a Cancellation Token
    StartWhile(intervalTime);
}

StartWhile(int interval) 
{
    while(!thread.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //Start work
        Thread.Sleep(interval);
    }
}
```

Note this is a rough example, not to be followed exactly just a general idea.